# Node.js Prevent to connect with revoked certificate

Tags: node.js, express

How to configure https server to prevent connect with revoked certificate

Comment: In production, you can use nginx as a proxy. It's easier!

Comment: The certificate lives on the server.  Why would it refuse to allow connections if its own certificate is revoked?  If its certificate is revoked, just shut down the program.

Comment: I think validating certificate revocation is a client setting.

Comment: @Brandon Surely he's talking about client certificates.

Comment: Good point.  People rarely talk about client certificates, so it didn't even come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: add to https options `crl` property - certificate revokation list

```
crl: fs.readFileSync(path.join('public', "ca-crl.pem"))
```